# problem in linux A JNI error has occurred linux

Tags: linux, burp

I have downloaded burpsuite pro version but I got this error while using this command

```
java -javaagent:BurpSuiteLoader_v2021.3.2.jar -noverify -jar burpsuite_pro_v2021.3.2.jar
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: burp/StartBurp has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Comment: " burp/StartBurp has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime". Have you try to upgrade your java version ?

Comment: NO ,   how i can upgrade my java ?

Comment: What is the output of  " java --version " ?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_212"

Comment: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
javac 11.0.11-ea

Comment: I used this command: sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove openjdk *

and now it's work thank you so much